# TSQL Order By - List of hard-coded values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that returns among others a Record Status column. The record status column has several values like: "Active", "Deleted", etc ...

I need to order the results by "Active", then "Deleted", then etc ...

I am currently creating CTEs to bring each set of records then UNION ALL. Is there a better and dynamic way of getting the query done?

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For more status values, you can do this:

```
WITH StatusOrders
AS
(
  SELECT StatusOrderID, StatusName
  FROM (VALUES(1, 'Active'), 
              (2, 'Deleted'),
              ...
              n, 'last status')) AS Statuses(StatusOrderID, StatusName)
)
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN StatusOrders s ON t.StatusName = s.StatusName
ORDER BY s.StatusOrderID;
```

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, I am getting an error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.

Comment: @Bill - Can you please show me the exact query you tried? it should work fine. Note that this synatx of `VALUES` within from is new in SQL Server 2008, if you are using old versions it won't work this way an you will have to `UNION ALL SELECT` the values instead.

Answer (score 7):

you can use `CASE` on here

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Status = 'Active' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
```

but if you have more values for `status` and you want to sort `Active` then `DELETE`

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Status = 'Active'  THEN 0 
              WHEN Status = 'Deleted' THEN 1
              ELSE 2 
         END ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
cteRiskStatus
AS
(
SELECT  RiskStatusID, RiskStatusName
FROM    (VALUES(1, 'Active'),
               (2, 'Draft'),
               (3, 'Occured'),
               (4, 'Escalated'),
               (5, 'Closed'),
               (6, 'Expired'),
               (7, 'Deleted')) AS RiskStatuses(RiskStatusID, RiskStatusName)
)
SELECT * FROM cteRiskStatus
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: It appears that I am using an instance of SQL 2005. I tried the above against a 2008 R2 instance and worked perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Bill, you need to finish the cte with a call to it so that it executes.