# sql order by hardcoded values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
select 'junior' as type, value
from mytable
union
select 'intermediate' as type, value
from mytable
union
select 'senior' as type, value
from mytable
```

Which returns the following data:

```
type          value

Intermediate     10    
Junior            5
Senior            1
```

I just need to reorder it so it looks like this

```
Junior          5
Intermediate   10        
Senior          1
```

I can't figure out which order by clause to use to achieve ordering by custom specific values, how would I achieve this?

Comment: See similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702927/tsql-order-by-list-of-hard-coded-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a third column, called e.g. sortorder. Then, assign the proper integer value to it,

```
select 'junior' as type, value, 1 as sortorder
from mytable
union
select 'intermediate' as type, value, 2 as sortorder
from mytable
union
select 'senior' as type, value, 3 as sortorder
from mytable
order by 3
```

Comment: Most simple answer, thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

You can either sort by adding a sort key column or add a simple case statement based on the values.

```sql
-- Sort with Case statement
with sourceData as
(
  select 'junior' type, 5 value
  union all
  select 'intermediate' type, 10 value
  union all
  select 'senior' type, 1 value
)
select * 
from sourceData
order by 
  case type
    when 'junior' then 0
    when 'intermediate' then 1
    when 'senior' then 2
    else null
  end
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/8409/0) for testing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if understood you well but I would extract one more column e.g. "sequence" with integer values. It will provide to the ability of applying custom order.

As an example:

```
select results.type, results.value, results.sequence 
from (    
    select 'junior' as type, value, 0 as sequence
    from mytable
    union
    select 'intermediate' as type, value, 1 as sequence
    from mytable
    union
    select 'senior' as type, value, 2 as sequence
    from mytable
) as results order by results.sequence
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.

select TYPE, value from 
(
select type,value , row_number() over ( order by type ) as rowno
from #mytable
union
select type, value, row_number() over ( order by type ) as rowno
from #mytable
union
select type,value, row_number() over ( order by type ) as rowno
from #mytable
)a order by 2 desc